# RegEx translation, can't find what it means

Tags: regex

I've looked in the MSDN, and Googled, and can't find how I should interpret this expression...

it's for an Address parameter....

```
^[a-zA-Z\\\d/\\\\\\\\]{0,80}$
```

I get that any upper/lower case letter, numbers are allowed, and it allows up to 80 characters.

I don't get what the 4 `\` are for.

I'm hoping that this regular expression allows for special characters since it's the street address entry field of a form . 
For example, I'm hoping this is saying something like 2400 Tam O'Shanter Place or 1904 Billings-Harper Terrace can be entered into the field.

Comment: Where is this from? Is this inside a string or a regex literal? Since all the characters are inside a character class, most of the backslashes are probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 redundant `\` characters (which are all escaped by `\`). You only need one (escaped, of course) to allow a literal `\` to be entered.

That said, this looks like a terrible way to validate street addresses:

- It doesn't allow hyphens, which are common (eg, `101-204 Main st`) or apostrophes (eg `O'shanter`) or several other characters used in addresses
- It's limiting the address entry to 80 characters, which seems arbitrary and possibly too short

Generally speaking, I wouldn't validate addresses, unless you actually want to do a post-office (or delivery company) lookup to validate it's a real, actual address, and even then it's fraught with problems (eg, new address that isn't in the database yet, or it includes a Suite # that is not in the database).

Payment processors will also let you validate addresses against the credit card numbers, mostly as a form of fraud protection.

What's the point of validation? If you're shipping something, the onus is on the customer (who is presumably both paying and entering this address) to validate the correct address. 
Until you know why it needs to be valid, and exactly what is "valid", you can't use validation.

You can maybe require non-blank, or a minimum # of characters, but even that may get you into trouble with international users (depending on scope of this app).